# Word for "hard to see because it's twinkling"?

Tags: word-request

Let's say, you see a star in a night sky. But you can't see it very well because it's twinkling and very far away. Is there a word like "faded" but that's related with twinkling and flickering?

Example sentence:

> The star was __ so I lost sight of it from time to time.

Comment: "faintly twinkling,"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! There is this gorgeous word 'evanesce'. It means 'fade or disappear in in a way that comes and goes'.

You can also describe your stars as being 'evanescent'.

Examples:

- As she turned towards him, his eyes sparkled and evanesced in a way that was echoed in the twinkling stars above them
- The champagne bubbles evanesced with a glittering gold light, caught by the flare of the candle-flame
- The fairies wings sparkled and evanesced with light as the child blinked and the fairy... suddenly disappeared
- the star was evanescent (so I lost sight of it from time to time) (brackets= possibly tautological as 'evanescent' already says it twinkles)
- the star was evanescent and I strained to see - was it yellow, gold or a figment of my imagination?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evanescent